# How can I override the AmplifyTheme in my react native app

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm making an app that uses Amazon Cognito authentication, via amplify add auth.  It is my first time using it so I decided not to customize the UI too much, but I am trying to override the AmplifyTheme styles listed [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify-react-native/src/AmplifyTheme.js), as instructed by the documentation [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#customize-ui-theme).

Here is my attempt to override the AmplifyTheme:

```
const MyButton = Object.assign({}, AmplifyTheme.button, { 
backgroundColor: '#A7B1B2' });

const myNavBar = Object.assign({}, AmplifyTheme.navBar, { marginTop: 
35, padding: 15, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', 
alignItems: 'center'});

const myTheme = Object.assign({}, AmplifyTheme, { button: MyButton, 
navBar: myNavBar });
```

At the bottom of my App.js file I have the following, according to the Amplify Authentication documentation:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App,
  includeGreetings = true,
  authenticatorComponents = [],
  federated = null,
  theme = {myTheme});
```

However, the Greeting style is unchanged!  Does anyone know how to override the AmplifyTheme??

Comment: Solved this issue by diving into the node modules for this project, finding the AmplifyTheme.js file and changing the button and navbar styling there.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a separate file with the custom theme.
`export` that theme file in your `withAuthenticator/Authenticator`

```js
//Custom theme
import {
  Authenticator,
  AmplifyTheme
} from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
const theme = {
  ...AmplifyTheme,
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    paddingTop: 10,
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: 30
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
  }
}
```

just refer to this post[custom module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55975665/8643391)